# Why is IE displaying NaN when all other browsers display correctly

Tags: javascript, date, internet-explorer, math

I am using a countdown timer script. I have been able to successfully get the results I desire on Google Chrome, Microsoft Edge, Mozilla Firefox however when I go over to Microsoft Internet Explorer 11 the resulting countdown of Minutes and Seconds display as NaN.

Here is the script I am using

```
 <script>
 var today = new Date();
 var DD = today.getDate();
 var MM = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
 var YYYY = today.getFullYear();
 //let get the Difference in Sec btw the two dates
 var _DateFromDBProgEndDate = '<?php echo $query->Cutoff; ?>';
 var ProgEndTime = new Date(_DateFromDBProgEndDate);
 var TodayTime = new Date();

 var differenceTravel = ProgEndTime.getTime()- TodayTime.getTime() ;
 var seconds = Math.floor((differenceTravel) / (1000));

 var SecDiffFromToday = seconds;
 var seconds = SecDiffFromToday;
 function timer() {
     var days        = Math.floor(seconds/24/60/60);
     var hoursLeft   = Math.floor((seconds) - (days*86400));
     var hours       = Math.floor(hoursLeft/3600);
     var minutesLeft = Math.floor((hoursLeft) - (hours*3600));
     var minutes     = Math.floor(minutesLeft/60);
     var remainingSeconds = seconds % 60;
     if (remainingSeconds < 10) {
         remainingSeconds = "0" + remainingSeconds; 
     }
     if (minutes < 10) {
       minutes = "0" + minutes; 
     }
     document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = minutes + ":" + remainingSeconds + " REMAINING";

    if (minutes > 15) {

        document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = "";
    }
if (hours > 0) {

    document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = "";
}

if (seconds == 0) {
    clearInterval(countdownTimer);
    document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = "CLOSED";
} else {
    seconds--;
  }
 }
 var countdownTimer = setInterval('timer()', 1000);
 </script>
```

Basically the script compares the current date and the cutoff date and produces the difference in time between the two. from there depending on the results the countdown appears. All works just as I had hoped in all browsers so far excluding IE, can anyone help me figure out why that is.

**EDIT**

When I echo $query->Cutoff; the date/time results as yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss

When viewing the code within the browser it appears as

```
 <script>
 var today = new Date();
 var DD = today.getDate();
 var MM = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
 var YYYY = today.getFullYear();
 //let get the Difference in Sec btw the two dates
 var _DateFromDBProgEndDate = '2018-07-18 23:15:00';
 var ProgEndTime = new Date(_DateFromDBProgEndDate);
 var TodayTime = new Date();

 var differenceTravel = ProgEndTime.getTime()- TodayTime.getTime() ;
 var seconds = Math.floor((differenceTravel) / (1000));

 var SecDiffFromToday = seconds;
 var seconds = SecDiffFromToday;
 function timer() {
    var days        = Math.floor(seconds/24/60/60);
    var hoursLeft   = Math.floor((seconds) - (days*86400));
    var hours       = Math.floor(hoursLeft/3600);
    var minutesLeft = Math.floor((hoursLeft) - (hours*3600));
    var minutes     = Math.floor(minutesLeft/60);
    var remainingSeconds = seconds % 60;
    if (remainingSeconds < 10) {
        remainingSeconds = "0" + remainingSeconds; 
    }
    if (minutes < 10) {
        minutes = "0" + minutes; 
    }
     document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = "minutes + ":" + remainingSeconds + " REMAINING";

    if (minutes > 15) {

        document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = "";
    }
    if (hours > 0) {

        document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = "";
    }

    if (seconds == 0) {
        clearInterval(countdownTimer);
        document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = "CLOSED";
    } else {
        seconds--;
    }
 }
 var countdownTimer = setInterval('timer()', 1000);
 </script>
```

**UPDATE**

With the advice from the community I was able to sort this one out and have it working in all browsers including the dreaded IE lol. Here is the code again with my edits, I have tried to comment where the changes are to better describe the solution for others.

Here is the final script

```
 <script>
 var today = new Date();
 var DD = today.getDate();
 var MM = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
 var YYYY = today.getFullYear();
 //let get the Difference in Sec btw the two dates
 // UPDATED HERE
 // I have updated the echo to control the output of the date/time. by doing this i can better control the output and equally successfully appease the IE Gods.
 var _DateFromDBProgEndDate = '<?php echo  date('Y/m/d H:i:s', strtotime($query->Cutoff)); ?>'; 
 var ProgEndTime = new Date(_DateFromDBProgEndDate);
 var TodayTime = new Date();

 var differenceTravel = ProgEndTime.getTime()- TodayTime.getTime() ;
 var seconds = Math.floor((differenceTravel) / (1000));

 var SecDiffFromToday = seconds;
 var seconds = SecDiffFromToday;
 function timer() {
     var days        = Math.floor(seconds/24/60/60);
     var hoursLeft   = Math.floor((seconds) - (days*86400));
     var hours       = Math.floor(hoursLeft/3600);
     var minutesLeft = Math.floor((hoursLeft) - (hours*3600));
     var minutes     = Math.floor(minutesLeft/60);
     var remainingSeconds = seconds % 60;
     if (remainingSeconds < 10) {
         remainingSeconds = "0" + remainingSeconds; 
     }
     if (minutes < 10) {
       minutes = "0" + minutes; 
     }
     document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = minutes + ":" + remainingSeconds + " REMAINING";

    if (minutes > 15) {

        document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = "";
    }
if (hours > 0) {

    document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = "";
}

if (seconds == 0) {
    clearInterval(countdownTimer);
    document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = "CLOSED";
} else {
    seconds--;
  }
 }
 var countdownTimer = setInterval('timer()', 1000);
 </script>
```

Much obliged to all who assisted and pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: IE is extremely picky about Date format. I'm guessing `_DateFromDBProgEndDate ` is returning a date is a format this isn't exactly following Date spec. (For instance, I believe IE requires `-`, not `/`, and doesn't recognize all orders to dates.)

Comment: provide a runnable example with real output of `echo $query->Cutoff;` as seen in browser source

Comment: @charlietfl I have updated the code, the echo is producing the values and is working on the other browsers just can't muster why pesky ole IE won't work with me lol. any insight would be great.

Comment: Ok that isn't a valid ISO date format. As mentioned above that is the issue. Will generate an invalid date in new Date. Some browsers are more tolerant to invalid formats if they think they can create a valid date from them

Comment: Please read the note under the `dateString` parameter ~ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Parameters. Basically, you'll want to use ISO 8601 format **only**, eg "2018-07-18T23:15:00Z"

Comment: reviewing and making alterations now, changing the echo to better comply with the parameers you have pointed me to :)

Comment: Alternatively, get PHP to echo out a unix timestamp and use that (x 1000 as JS uses milliseconds)

Comment: awesome support to a fellow coder guys, I was banging my head and blind as a bat apparently. I modified the echo a bit and boom we have a successful timer :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

With the advice from the community I was able to sort this one out and have it working in all browsers including the dreaded IE lol. Here is the code again with my edits, I have tried to comment where the changes are to better describe the solution for others.

Here is the final script

```
<script>
 var today = new Date();
 var DD = today.getDate();
 var MM = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
 var YYYY = today.getFullYear();
 //let get the Difference in Sec btw the two dates
 // UPDATED HERE
 // I have updated the echo to control the output of the date/time. by doing this i can better control the output and equally successfully appease the IE Gods.
 var _DateFromDBProgEndDate = '<?php echo  date('Y/m/d H:i:s', strtotime($query->Cutoff)); ?>'; 
 var ProgEndTime = new Date(_DateFromDBProgEndDate);
 var TodayTime = new Date();

 var differenceTravel = ProgEndTime.getTime()- TodayTime.getTime() ;
 var seconds = Math.floor((differenceTravel) / (1000));

 var SecDiffFromToday = seconds;
 var seconds = SecDiffFromToday;
 function timer() {
     var days        = Math.floor(seconds/24/60/60);
     var hoursLeft   = Math.floor((seconds) - (days*86400));
     var hours       = Math.floor(hoursLeft/3600);
     var minutesLeft = Math.floor((hoursLeft) - (hours*3600));
     var minutes     = Math.floor(minutesLeft/60);
     var remainingSeconds = seconds % 60;
     if (remainingSeconds < 10) {
         remainingSeconds = "0" + remainingSeconds; 
     }
     if (minutes < 10) {
       minutes = "0" + minutes; 
     }
     document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = minutes + ":" + remainingSeconds + " REMAINING";

    if (minutes > 15) {

        document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = "";
    }
if (hours > 0) {

    document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = "";
}

if (seconds == 0) {
    clearInterval(countdownTimer);
    document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = "CLOSED";
} else {
    seconds--;
  }
 }
 var countdownTimer = setInterval('timer()', 1000);
 </script>
```

Alternatively as the previous code will utilize the Client Side time I have also updated the script to include the server times by adding a few php variables as shown below.

```
  // added in the date values via php in order to get the server time as opposed to the client times for a more accurate countdown.
<?php
    date_default_timezone_set('America/Toronto');
    $currentdate =  date("o/n/N");
    $currentday = date("N");
    $currentmonth = date("n");
    $currentyear = date("o");
    $currenttime= date("Y/m/d H:i:s");
?>
<script>
var today = <?php echo $currentdate; ?>;
var DD = <?php echo $currentday; ?>;
var MM = <?php echo $currentmonth; ?>; //January is 0!
var YYYY = <?php echo $currentyear; ?>;
//let get the Difference in Sec btw the two dates
var _DateFromDBProgEndDate = '<?php echo date('Y/m/d H:i:s', strtotime($inpersonresult->BidCutoff)); ?>';
var ProgEndTime = new Date(_DateFromDBProgEndDate);
var _TodayTime = '<?php echo date('Y/m/d H:i:s', strtotime($currenttime)); ?>';
var TimeOfToday = new Date(_TodayTime);

var differenceTravel = ProgEndTime.getTime()- TimeOfToday.getTime() ;
var seconds = Math.floor((differenceTravel) / (1000));

var SecDiffFromToday = seconds;
var seconds = SecDiffFromToday;
function timer() {
    var days        = Math.floor(seconds/24/60/60);
    var hoursLeft   = Math.floor((seconds) - (days*86400));
    var hours       = Math.floor(hoursLeft/3600);
    var minutesLeft = Math.floor((hoursLeft) - (hours*3600));
    var minutes     = Math.floor(minutesLeft/60);
    var remainingSeconds = seconds % 60;
    if (remainingSeconds < 10) {
        remainingSeconds = "0" + remainingSeconds; 
    }
    if (minutes < 10) {
        minutes = "0" + minutes; 
    }
     document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = "WARNING:SUBMISSIONS MUST BE RECEIVED BEFORE <?php echo date('l,F j,Y h:i a', strtotime($query->Cutoff)); ?><br>"+ minutes + ":" + remainingSeconds + " REMAINING";

    if (minutes >= 15) {

        document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = "";
    }
        if (hours > 0) {

        document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = "";
    }

    if (seconds == 0) {
         clearInterval(countdownTimer);
        document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = "CLOSED";
        window.location='https://example.com/closed/';
    } else {
        seconds--;
    }
}
var countdownTimer = setInterval('timer()', 1000);
</script>
```

I tried using all ISO-8601 accepted formats however when doing so I did find a few adverse results and as such have set the CurrentTime and the date produced by the database to Y/m/d. The biggest issue I have found with IE is that they do not like seeing hyphens within the date formats and it seems to negatively effect the results. When I removed the hyphens and added in the slashes again this script worked on all 4 browsers as well as android and iphone devices alike.

I also added in a redirect when the timer runs out which takes them right off the page to another window where you can hold an error message of your choosing.

Comment: This looks like it's going to potentially suffer from exactly the same issue. Why aren't you using ISO 8601 format or a timestamp?

Comment: I am reworking the entire thing to change from client side to server side times all around but this was the answer to why it was not populating correctly in IE, I agree there are better methods and many other methods however this was the simpliest way to solve the question as to why it was not appearing in IE. I can add an edit later with the new script using all server side times or those who want to go either way with it.

Comment: and it does in fact work. on IE, Chrome, Firefox, Edge and Safari from what I have tested so far so it is in truth a viable solution that I hope others will find helpful.

Comment: The issue is that support for various date string formats is not guaranteed whereas an ISO 8601 format  or a Unix timestamp in ms will **always** work

Comment: I am researching that however when addressing the issue in your initial comment you noted  eg "2018-07-18T23:15:00Z" but the hyphens were the issue why the numbers were not populating in IE and are a bit of a known issue. I will look into updating my answer to add other options but I dont feel that this answer should have been downvoted as it does solve the issue. The manner which I called the time is a standard method in php and appears all over the stack answers so I feel confident that simple php date structures such as this will be supported for many years to come as it already has :)

Comment: It's not just about slashes vs hyphens. The ISO 8601 format is a universally recognised and accepted string representation of a date. There's a vast difference between what you originally had (`2018-07-18 23:15:00`) and the ISO string `2018-07-18T23:15:00Z`. It may not look like much on the surface but believe me, it makes all the difference when parsing

Comment: was reviewing over night, I will get my answer updated today. just dealing with a couple other fires that I need to put out first. thanks for your insight, every day is an opportunity to learn something new ;)

Comment: If you want to shoot an example of this script working with your methods I would love to see it but as it stands when I tried a few different ways it just would not produce the correct resulting functionality. I respect the concern but a lot of php date formats shown on a tonne of scripts on stack also use Y/m/d and is represented in the w3c and php.net sites formats. If you have the time I would love to review your version so that I can see another way to accomplish this task. thanks for your insight. I tried adding ISO Standard formats where I was able to in the php server time variation.